# Regex lookaround with special characters is invalid?

Tags: regex, special-characters, regex-lookarounds

I am trying this regex

```
(?<!(John|Joe)) (Taylor)
```

On this text
`John James Taylor`

but I am getting "invalid pattern in lookbehind" here http://www.rubular.com/r/TjD2d4oG5z

I am trying to match "Taylor" that does not have John or Joe before it.

Any tips please?

Comment: Is your regex flavor accept variable length lookbehind? Most of them don't.

Comment: Thanks! Just found out that variable length does not work in lookaround by this comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479131/problem-with-quantifiers-and-look-behind

In addition both of the answers are working with the proposed changes, but not if I add sg like \w+ because that is a variable length quantifier as I understand now :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
(?<!(?:John|Joe)) (Taylor)
```

`(?:)` is a non-capturing group, which makes sense in a lookaround, since you are merely doing an *assertion*, not actually *matching* anything. Or just remove the capturing group all together, that is, `(?<!John|Joe)`.

Comment: The non-capturing group is not necessary I think.

Comment: @xdazz: It's not, yes. I was just trying to point out that using a capturing group was the reason why the original regex was invalid.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
/(?<!John|Joe) (Taylor)/
```