# Can we use quantifiers inside a lookbehind expression?

Tags: java, regex-lookarounds

This question is specific to Java 7/8.

A fairly complex regex that uses quantifiers are prohibited inside lookbehind assertions such as this one:

```
(?<=(a|b*)*)bc
```

as it results in an runtime exception with a message like:

```
look-behind group does not have obvious maximum length error
```

I am guessing it is because quantifiers such as `*` and `+` are "generally" not allowed.

However, the following does work:

```
(?<=a*)bc
```

Why is this so?

There are similar posts about this issue on SO:

1. For other languages:
   [ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479131/problem-with-quantifiers-and-look-behind?rq=1), [PCRE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23964362/why-cant-you-use-repetition-quantifiers-in-zero-width-look-behind-assertions) etc-
2. Some posts are specific to Java but don't seem to provide concrete answers or references such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9030305/regular-expression-lookbehind-doesnt-work-with-quantifiers-or?rq=1) one. Mostly the answers state these quantifiers simply cannot be used. Also, [regular-expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) website states the same.
3. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24874404/java-regex-look-behind-group-does-not-have-obvious-maximum-length-error) states Java has bugs in it's look behind implementation.

However, the example that I have shown above that uses the zero or many quantifier `*` inside the lookbehind is valid for Java 7/8.

Any references or explanation would be helpful.

Comment: (Note: this is not specified by the JLS but by the library documentation.)

Comment: The [library documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) doesn't really specify it, either.  It refers you to an O'Reilly book that describes the specific behavior.

Comment: Thanks. I've made the correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at the `Pattern` code and trying to trace it, I'm convinced that this is just a bug.  Both examples should result in an exception.  But the logic that tests for this is incorrect.

This code appears in a couple places:

```
 temp = info.maxLength * cmax + maxL;
 info.maxLength = temp;
 if (temp < maxL) {
     info.maxValid = false;
 }
```

Note that as long as `maxLength` and `cmax` are nonnegative, `temp` should never be less than `maxL` unless overflow has occurred.  `maxValid` is eventually used by the lookbehind code; if `maxValid` is `false`, `"look-behind group does not have obvious maximum length error"` is thrown.

From what I can tell, in a regex like *<prefix>* *<expression>*`{m,n}`, in the above code, `info.maxLength` is the maximum length of "expression", `cmax` is the upper bound of the quantifier, and `maxL` is the maximum length of "prefix".  When a quantifier is `*` or `+`, the upper bound is set to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.  (All the variables here are `int`.)  This means that there will be overflow *unless `info.maxLength` is 1 and `maxL` is 0*.  That's exactly the case with

```
(?<=a*)bc
```

since the pattern with the quantifier has length 1, and there is nothing before the `a*` which means `maxL` will be 0.  That's why this case falls through the cracks.

For any other values, the computation will overflow, but that doesn't necessarily mean `temp < maxL` will be true.  If `info.maxLength` is even, then an exception will be thrown; but if `info.maxLength` is odd, the pattern will compile if `maxL` is small enough.  This is because of the way wraparound works, mathematically; the code that attempts to check for overflow is quite faulty.  This means that

```
(?<=a*)bc         // succeeds
(?<=(ab)*)bc      // throws exception
(?<=(abc)*)bc     // succeeds
(?<=(abcd)*)bc    // throws exception
(?<=(abcde)*)bc   // succeeds
```

Also:

```
(?<=xa*)bc        // throws exception
(?<=x(abc)*)bc    // succeeds
```

**Note:** It should be noted that in your example regex, lookbehind is  useless:

```
(?<=a*)bc
```

The lookbehind says to test whether the current location is preceded by zero or more occurrences of the letter `a`.  This is always true, trivially.  So the lookbehind serves no purpose here.  Similarly,

```
(?<=a+)bc
```

is equivalent to

```
(?<=a)bc
```

since as long as there's one `a` preceding the current location, it doesn't matter how many more there might be.  The same is true of all the examples that don't throw an exception, except for this one:

```
(?<=x(abc)*)bc    // succeeds
```

since here the matcher does have to go backwards looking for `abc`'s in the string and making sure the last one is preceded by `x`.  It seems that `Pattern` should throw an exception in this case, but because of the faulty overflow-check logic, it isn't.  Therefore, I'm uncertain whether it would actually return the correct result, or whether it might crash or go into an infinite loop.  However, I haven't tried it.

Really, the code should just check directly whether `cmax` is equal to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, instead of using it in computation and hoping the code can tell later that the result is bogus.